# Prometheus not running with OpenFaaS

Tags: prometheus, openfaas

I just installed OpenFaaS on Kubernetes and was able to deploy and invoke a simple hello-world-type function (which means OpenFaaS is working correctly). However, [the guide I am following](https://blog.alexellis.io/first-faas-python-function/) states that I should then be able to access the Prometheus UI at http://localhost:9090/. Clicking that link results in an error message:

```
This site can’t be reached - localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How can I view the Prometheus UI in OpenFaaS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you must run this command first:
`kubectl port-forward deployment/prometheus 9090:9090 -n openfaas`

Source: https://github.com/openfaas/workshop/blob/master/lab9.md